# Create image with audio and concate to another video

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

Please help me understand! I spent a lot of time...:( Thank you!

I'm stuck with a problem. I have a stream with damaged video and normal audio. And 2nd video, continued, with normal video and audio. I want to attach a picture to the beginning of an undamaged video with normal audio from damaged video without re-encoding the normal video.

I try this one:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loop 1 -framerate 50 -t 3478 -i image.jpg -t 3478 -i audio.mp3 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [2:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" output.mp4
```

But it converts normal video.

Mediainfo from normal video:

```
      Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:56:31.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3726 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3594 kb/s, 27.46 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: You're adding the normal video to the concat filter, so it will be decoded and then re-encoded. Combine the image and audio MP3 and convert to same codec and timescale as video.mp4 and then use concat demuxer.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me advice how I can create video from reference?